# Is It Possible To Use Nats JetStream with EncodedConn?

Tags: go, nats.io

I'm working on convert Nats core to Nats jetstream  on a go project. I'm using nats.go and as I notice EncodedConn request is used everywhere in transporter files. But EncodedConn doesn't support Jetstream "noticed during debugging".
I had to use Nats native request method with Marshal , Unmarshal manually. And I had to repeat this twice, one for subscription and another for transporter. Is there anyway to make it simplest ? I shared a code snippet to make it clear.

I couldn't be able to use encodedconn cause the return type is different than *nats.Msg and  I encountered this error **"msgpack: invalid code=7b decoding map length"**

**Transporter File**

```
func (t *Transport) GetProvidersLastblock(provider string) (lastblock LastblockDTO, err error) {

    req := LastblockDTO{Provider: provider,}

    listblockJson, _ := json.Marshal(req)

    msg ,err := t.Conn.Request("LASTBLOCK.GETPROVIDER", listblockJson, GlobalNatsLastblockTimeout)

    json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, &lastblock)
    return 
}
```

**Subscribe File**

```
func getProvidersLastblock(srv *service.Service) (sb *nats.Subscription, err error) {
    js,_ := srv.Tp.Conn.JetStream()
    sb, err = js.Subscribe(subjectName,
        func(msg *nats.Msg) {
            msg.Ack()
            var lastblockDto transporter.LastblockDTO
            json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, &lastblockDto)
            lastblock, err := srv.Db.GetProviderLastblock(lastblockDto.Provider)

            if err != nil {
                srv.Log2.Error(err, "fn", "getProvidersLastblock")
            }
            lastblockJSON, _ := json.Marshal(lastblock)
            _, err = srv.JS.Publish(subjectName, lastblockJSON)

            if err != nil {
                srv.Log2.Error(err, "fn", "publishProvidersLastblock")
            }
        }, nats.Durable("monitor"), nats.ManualAck())

    return
}
```